# JMX example password file restrictions

Tags: java, jmx, restriction

I downloaded the JMX example client/agent from the oracle site, and when I try to run it, according to this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html, from a normal cmd, it says:

```
Can't read password file
```

And when I try to run it from an elevated cmd, it says:

```
Password File acces must be restricted
```

I used this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/security-windows.html to regulate the acces to the password file.

Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the tutorial does not require (or provide) the authentication part. Therefore you should not need the password file to run the JMX examples.

Secondly, the password file must be readable **ONLY** by the user you use to run the authenticated JMX server - usually the current user. If it is accessible by any other users/groups as well you will get:

> Password File acces must be restricted

If you follow the guide to set up the access rights make sure in step 8 that the only entry left is the one of your current user.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/the_hidden_command_that_would) explains exactly how to use **cacls.exe** to do this.

Comment: this says pretty much the same as the link I used ;) But thanks anyway!